# Design Patterns: Stop user from deleting certain configurations

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns

My application has configuration options which stores the application preferences and some of the network configuration of the other nodes it's talking to. The application features a scheduling logic to make use any of the network configuration to execute the scheduled job. If any of the configurations used for scheduled jobs, the application shouldn't allow to delete it.

I am using database tables to store the configurations. Adding a single boolean value to mention if it is being used can help to me to sort out the problem but what's the right way to implement this?

Comment: Are you storing scheduled jobs in the DB too?

Comment: @Anri Yes. I am storing the information about the scheduled job info in the DB

Comment: I follow a similar principle on a particular application - schedules have an active/inactive flag and an optional valid date range, which can also set the inactive flag when elapsed. Keeping the config flexible in this manner as well as separate is quite elegant, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Don't see anything wrong in your solution. 
Keeping smple `boolean` or `bit` value that indicates either the field is used or not is perfectly acceptable. Also it scales good among different databses (in the moment you decide, fot some reason, to change database).

Cause if you indtroduce some database dependent security policy, for permission check, you would be strongly coupled with *that* database.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Engine can handle data integrity itself. You just have to set up keys and delete/update rules.

See

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190765(v=sql.105).aspx  - general info on data integrity
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463(v=sql.105).aspx - how to create FOREIGN KEY constraint

This way you will have to catch constraint violation exceptions (`ConstraintException`) and handle it by informing a user.

NB. As @Tigran said, nothing wrong with your solution too.